# HTML anchors & links on fixed element

Tags: html

I have some target elements (`<div name="target">`) in my document and links to them are inside a fixed positioned element. (`<a href="#target">`).

Somehow the anchors and links don't work by default. Clicking the link inside the fixed positioned element doesn't do anything (the page doesn't scroll to where it should).

Target element has no gimmicks. It's just a div element inside few other div's.

Comment: You need to escape your code by putting \`backticks\` around them. We can't see the html :P

Comment: What (X)HTML version/variant do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC, you need to assign an `id` instead of a `name` when doing this for elements other than `<a>` tags.

Comment: +1, you do recall correctly :-) *name* is actually removed from HTML5 for *IMG*, *FORM* and *A* elements.  http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-diff-20080610/#absent-attributes

Answer (score 1):

By doing this:

You're effectively saying that the link must go to an element in the document where the **id** is named "target"

so change,

```
<div name="target">
```

to

```
<div id="target">
```